# Passing a function argument with dots

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a function to compute sample sizes in R.

The function uses a couple of smaller functions.  I'd like to pass arguments into the smaller functions using the dots.  Here is my function so far:

```
log_reg_var<-function(p){
  if(p<=0|p>=1) stop('p must be between 0 and 1')
  var<-1/(p*(1-p))
  return(var)
}

samplesize<-function(method_name, beta, sigma_x, mult_cor, power= 0.8,fpr = 0.05,...){

  if(method_name=='linear regression'){
    var_func <- lin_reg_var
  }
  else if(method_name=='logistic regression'){
    var_func <- log_reg_var
  }
  else if(method_name=='cox regression'){
    var_func <- cox_reg_var
  }
  else if(method_name=='poisson regression'){
    var_func <- pois_reg_var
  }
  else{
    stop('method_name not recognized. method_name accepts one of: "linear regression",
         "logistic regression","cox regression", or "poisson regression"')
  }

  top = (qnorm(1-fpr/2) + qnorm(power))^2
  bottom = (beta*sigma_x)^2*(1-mult_cor)

  n = (top/bottom)*var_func(...)

  return(ceiling(n))

}
```

I should be able to do

```
samplesize(method_name = 'logreg',1,1,0,p=0.5)
>>>32
```

But instead I am thrown the following error:

```
Error in var_func(...) : argument "p" is missing, with no default
```

Clearly there is something wrong with me passing `p` through the dots, but I'm not sure what is wrong.

What is my problem here?

Comment: is `p` in the `log_reg_var()` function supposed to be the `power` in the `power` parameter in the `sample size` function?

Comment: No.  `p` is supposed  to be passed to `log_reg_var()`.  The `power` parameter, if not specified, should be 0.8.  Is that clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the additional parameter `p` as an argument and you need to pass it into your `log_reg_var()` function. You also have to be careful with some other syntax:

```
log_reg_var<-function(p){
  if(p<=0|p>=1) stop('p must be between 0 and 1')
  var<-1/(p*(1-p))
  return(var)
}

# specify that you pass a parameter `p`
samplesize<-function(method_name, beta, sigma_x, mult_cor, power= 0.8,fpr = 0.05, p, ...){

# Initialize `var_func` to a NULL value
var_func = NULL

  if(method_name=='linear regression'){
    var_func <- lin_reg_var(p)
  }
  else if(method_name=='logistic regression'){
    # pass parameter `p` into log_reg_var since there is no default
    var_func <- log_reg_var(p)
  }
  else if(method_name=='cox regression'){
    var_func <- cox_reg_var(p)
  }
  else if(method_name=='poisson regression'){
    var_func <- pois_reg_var(p)
  }
  else{
    stop('method_name not recognized. method_name accepts one of: "linear regression",
     "logistic regression","cox regression", or "poisson regression"')
  }

  top = (qnorm(1-fpr/2) + qnorm(power))^2
  bottom = (beta*sigma_x)^2*(1-mult_cor)

  n = (top/bottom)*var_func

  return(ceiling(n))

}

> samplesize(method_name ='logistic regression', 1, 1, 0, p=0.5)
[1] 32
```